# List accessible AirPrint Printers

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintinfo

I would like to show a list with all printer accessible by the device via AirPrint.

I get it working with using the `UIPrinterPickerController`.

Is there anyway displaying this PickerController in a custom way, let's say feeding the data into a `UITableView`?

Also note that I'm planning to use this App on an iPad which only supports the `UIPrinterPickerController.presentFromRect(CGRect)`

Here's how it looks right now. Instead of this popup there should be a `UITableView`

[image: Printer Popup]

Comment: I'm wondering if with `printerPickerController:shouldShowPrinter:` you can retrieve all the `UIPrinter`, since it should get called for each printers. You may have to call the show the `UIPrinterPickerController` (and hide it, or in a invisible part of the screen, quick dismiss, I don't know when the delegate method should be call, i.e.. if cell willShow, or already set) in order that the previous method of `UIPrinterPickerControllerDelegate` gets called.

Answer (score 2):

the `NSNetServiceBrowser` is precisely for this.

In short, what you need to do is:

1) set an object as the NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate
2) create a NSNetServiceBrowser object
3) assign the delegate
4) using `browserObject.searchForServices(ofType: "_printer._tcp.", inDomain: "")` will get various feedback to the delegate.

A simple test on my end got:

```
didFind: Samsung C460 Series (SEC001174EDCB63)
```

for the delegate method:

```
func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
    print("didFind: \(service.name)")
}
```

Comment: This is looking good so far. Can only test next week though, since I myself don't have any AirPrint printers

Comment: For those like me who tried to understand this answer without a good knowledge of objective-c / swift, beware that this is explained with more details under https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/BrowsingForServices.html.